# Split and replace all strings in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, split

I have a large dataframe where each row contains a string.
I want to split each string into several columns, and also replace two character types.

The code below does the job, but it is slow on a large dataframe. Is there a faster way than using a for loop?

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['[3.4, 3.4, 2.5]', '[3.4, 3.4, 2.5]'])

df_new = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0,0], 'col2': [0,0], 'col3': [0,0]})

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df_new.iloc[i, :] = re.split(',', df.iloc[i, 0].replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['[3.4, 3.4, 2.5]', '[3.4, 3.4, 2.5]'])

df_new = df[0].str[1:-1].str.split(",", expand=True)
df_new.columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
```

The idea is to first get rid of the `[` and `]` and then split by `,` and expand the dataframe. The last step would be to rename the columns.

Comment: Great, this is much faster than my loop!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should be changed with [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df1 = df[0].str.strip('[]').str.split(', ', expand=True).add_prefix('col')
print(df1)
  col0 col1 col2
0  3.4  3.4  2.5
1  3.4  3.4  2.5
```

If performance is important use list comprehension instead pandas functions:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.strip('[]').split(', ') for x in df[0]]).add_prefix('col')
```

**Timings**:

```
#20k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [208]: %timeit df[0].str.strip('[]').str.split(', ', expand=True).add_prefix('col')
61.5 ms ± 1.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [209]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([x.strip('[]').split(', ') for x in df[0]]).add_prefix('col')
29.8 ms ± 1.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```